# How to set log4j version 2.3 encoding

Tags: xml, encoding, utf-8, log4j2

I've used log-4-j version 2.3 in my web application.
Everything is good but Unicode character are logged as '?' in destination file.
How can I set character encoding as Unicode 8 to prevent this problem?
here is my sample code :
I've wrote a main method to run my test on eclipse it worked properly.but when is run this jeryey web service from from browser (my app server is weblogic), all persian characters are appeard as  '?' in the log file:

```java
public static void main(String[] args ) {
    UserRestServices service = new UserRestServices();
    service.test();
}

@Path("test")
@GET
public String test() {
    String newString;
    try {
        newString = new String("فارسی".getBytes(), "UTF8");
        APLogManager.infoLogger.info(newString);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "test compeleted";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set the charset of the layout. For example:

```
<PatternLayout
    charset="UTF-8"
    pattern="%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n" />
```

Comment: it doesn't work, I've added some new information to the Question detail for more clarity

Comment: When you create the newString object, you're using an array of bytes that represent the Persian string in your platform's default character encoding.  I assume this is not UTF8. You then create the newString object by telling Java to interpret these bytes as a UTF8-encoded string. This will not work and results in ???? output, whether you use log4j or System.out.println.

Comment: The solution is to change your config to set `charset="UTF-8"`, then simply log your Persian strings without trying to manually convert the encoding: `APLogManager.infoLogger.info("فارسی");`.

Comment: by adding the parameter "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 " to the  java command it  worked properly. thanx a lot.